# installing realvnc with pip

Tags: python, python-2.7, vnc, vnc-viewer

I would like to use realvnc python api binding for one of my python script. is there any ways to install via pip ?

I tried `pip install realvnc` and `pip install vncsdk` both did not work for me.

Any helps would be appreciated.

Comment: A google for `pip install realvnc` doesn't show any matching results. Why did you think that would work?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to install via pip

No, you must sign-in to download. https://developer.realvnc.com/download/

How to use it? You need to move the `vncsdk.py` file into your Python path "and also the SDK’s native bindings (the SDK shared library, or DLL)"

> In order for the Python runtime to locate the SDK, you may need to append the location of the bindings to the `sys.path` variable before importing the bindings. Alternatively, you can install the bindings in a global location such as `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/` or `C:\Python27\lib\site-packages` (depending on your system and Python version).

And then, you should be able to import

> ```
> import vncsdk
> ```

https://developer.realvnc.com/docs/latest/api/python/index.html

Comment: Hi @cricket_007, Thanks for your help. I am using Python 2.7.As you suggested I copied vncsdk.py file to C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages folder. Do I need to add another variable on the Environment Variables for this. When I try to import, I get the following error;

Comment: >>> import vncsdk
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\vncsdk.py", line 144, in <module>
    VNCSDK_LIBRARY = _find_library()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\vncsdk.py", line 130, in _find_library
    raise ImportError("could not find the SDK shared object: place it in the sys
tem path or set the VNCSDK_LIBRARY environment variable to point to it")
ImportError: could not find the SDK shared object: place it in the system path o
r set the VNCSDK_LIBRARY environment variable to point to it

Comment: Read the link again... "you will need to include not only the bindings themselves, vncsdk.py, but **also the SDK’s native bindings (the SDK shared library, or DLL)**"

Comment: Thanks a lot ;) @cricket_007